# Google Cloud / App Engine (Node JS) "Error: EIO: i/o error, read"

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We have a Node JS app deployed on Google Cloud/App Engine. The app just started reporting an IO Error:

```
Error: EIO: i/o error, read
   at .Object.readSync ( fs.js:617 )
   at .tryReadSync ( fs.js:382 )
   at .Object.readFileSync ( fs.js:411 )
   at Object.Module._extensions..js ( internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1112 )
   ...
```

[image: google cloud platform error io error file read]

Here's what I will try to do:

- Restart the App Engine instances/servers https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/restart-services
- Delete `node_modules` folders and re-install https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17030

I will update the question with any findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We experienced the same issue this morning along the same timeline. Looks like there was an incident:

https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/mvpNTsgUmf2LL7PdgmyF

https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/g4uX8eZKYFI

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230635334

Comment: Thank you, John! Eventually the issue fixed itself for me, sounds like that's consistent with the issue/incident you linked.